# Plug-in for Monogame on Visual Studios

Tags: c#, monogame, visual-studio-setup

I create a brand new file in visual studios, MonoGame Windows Project.  Then I run it and I get an instant error.  What is the problem?  Error states:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in SharpDX.XInput.dll

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'xinput1_3.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

```
     if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
          //this is what is causing the error
```

Comment: are you familiar with how to add `using` to the .cs class file header.. also are you manually adding the references to the `References` node in the project. can you show what your using section in the header looks like..?

Comment: It seems you're lacking some DirectX libraries, have you installed the latests DirectX runtimes?

Comment: http://community.monogame.net/t/unable-to-load-dll-xinput1-3-dll-on-windows-8-1/2118

Comment: I am not manually adding anything, the only thing I did was create a new file.  If you run it, a empty window should pop up. But I get an error.  I wasnt sure if there was a plugin I was missing and No I have not installed DirectX..I will do that now

Comment: You are missing the DirectX SDK, this is a common error.

Comment: Thanks that was the Issue

Comment: @Groo if you put this as the answer I would have given you credit.  And someone gave me a downgrade.  So Im trying to fix my downgrades so that I can ask a question.

Comment: @nameishi: you can accept Neill's answer below, that's basically the same solution.

Comment: @Groo so why the downgrade?

Comment: @nameishi: hi, no, I didn't downvote this, I don't think your question is "unclear and not useful".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get around this issue by downloading and installing the DirectX End-User Runtimes (June 2010) from this link: https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/A/84A35BF1-DAFE-4AE8-82AF-AD2AE20B6B14/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe

Answer (score 0):

Adding DirectXEnd plug in solved the problem.  Thanks